# jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu onSlideListener

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I'm using jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu library in my Android project. Is there any easy way to get a current slide offset value? Something like we have in Google `DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener.onDrawerSlide (View drawerView, float slideOffset)?`

Comment: I've solved my problem. In CustomViewAbove.java file there is a function `getPercentOpen()`. You can use it for making listener.

Comment: How to implement this listener?

Comment: Hi. You have to create an interface like MyListener with method i.e. onSlide(double percentage).

Next set a listener in CustomViewAbove class - create a method like:

    `public void setMyListener(MyListener listener) {
        this.myListener = listener;
    }`
Last step is to call onSlide method from

    `getPercentOpen()`
like 

    `protected float getPercentOpen() {
        float percentage = Math.abs(mScrollX-mContent.getLeft()) / getBehindWidth();
        if (this.myListener != null) {
            this.myListener.onSlide(percentage);
        }

        return percentage;
    }`

Comment: hmm, so we must edit the library directly, thank you for discovering this :). I hope the developer can update the library to support offset although now we have navigation drawer

Comment: I'm trying to do this too. can i see your code how you created the interface and such?